# MS Access application return value

Tags: ms-access, vba, return-value

I need to make automatic application called from windows command line. This app start, make some DB operations and automatically exit. 
Next I need to handle return values from Access. I tried everything what I find on Google but Access returns 0 every time. I need to return 1 or something else to tell cmd that there is error in database.

here is some code in VBA (access call Form when application starts):

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim xSQL As String
    Dim xRS As DAO.Recordset

    xSQL = "select * from table1"
    Set xRS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(xSQL, dbOpenDynaset)
    xRS.MoveLast: xRS.MoveFirst

    DoEvents

    If xRS!field1 = "" Or IsNull(xRS!field1) Then
        ' HERE I WANT TO RETURN 1 OR ANY TRUE VALUE = ERROR
        Application.Quit acQuitSaveAll
    End If

    ' HERE I RETURN 0 = SUCCESS
    Application.Quit acQuitSaveAll
End Sub
```

Some ideas how to do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [parent child environment variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19410574/parent-child-environment-variables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your best solution can be setting an environment variable with the desired return value.

From your VBA code:

```
Private Declare Function SetEnvironmentVariable Lib "kernel32" _
Alias "SetEnvironmentVariableA" _
(ByVal lpName As String, _
ByVal lpValue As String) As Long


Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim xSQL As String
    Dim xRS As DAO.Recordset

    xSQL = "select * from table1"
    Set xRS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(xSQL, dbOpenDynaset)
    xRS.MoveLast: xRS.MoveFirst

    DoEvents

    If xRS!field1 = "" Or IsNull(xRS!field1) Then
        SetEnvironmentVariable "ACCESSEXITCODE", "1"
        Application.Quit acQuitSaveAll
    End If

        SetEnvironmentVariable "ACCESSEXITCODE", "0"
    Application.Quit acQuitSaveAll
End Sub
```

From de command line:

```
IF %ACCESSEXITCODE%==1 GOTO HandleError
```

Comment: As already noted by @johnny-bones this does not work. See  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19410574/parent-child-environment-variables